# What is the best way to allow users to change templates?

Tags: templates, static-files

In one of my project, my users will have a dedicated part of my website ({username}.example.org). In that subdomain, I plan to allow them to change the design easily.
I took a look at some online website that already does that, like [Tumblr](http://tumblr.com), [Posterous](http://posterous.com) and [Shopify](http://shopify.com).

Regarding the language of this application, I started it with Django, which I succeedly implemented a *"template rendering based on the url name with default as fallback"* (http://someuser.example.com will load the templates in templates/someuser/* or in templates/generic/* if not found in the first).
But I can export it to PHP or Play!Framework if they are more adapted to my needs.

The template engine used is [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/), since it is as simple as Django template engine, easy to learn, and safe (no Python coode can (should normally!) be executed).

Here is the Pros/Cons of each solution I found. I would really appreciate your thoughts on that and which way you would do, why. Thanks.

Note: The users will have a good knowledge in HTML/CSS.

**Changing vars (like title color, etc)**

- Pros:

  1. Simple & secure
- Cons:

  1. Too limited, an user that want to personalize his website won't be able to do so with this solution

**Only upload CSS**

- Pros:

  1. Simple to integrate
  2. Secure
- Cons:

  1. Limited
  2. Where the user image are stored? (logo, background, some gradient, etc)

**Allow user to edit templates (stored in the database)**

- Pros:

  1. Changes are more important
  2. The user is (almost) free to do whatever he wants (implements GA, FeedBurner, etc)
- Cons:

  1. Where do they put the static files (logo, background-image, some special effect (gradient))?
  2. Template are stored in the database, which require one more SQL request for each page displayed

**Allow user to edit templates (stored in files)**

- Pros:

  1. Changes are more important
  2. The user is (almost) free to do whatever he wants (implements GA, FeedBurner, etc)
  3. A FTP access can be enabled, rooting the user in his Template dir.
- Cons:

  1. The same problem for the static files

Also, where I'm stuck is about how to handle static files (images, css, js) : I can't see how to define a VirtualHost in Apache (or NGinx) that would request the database to see which users belongs this url.

Thanks for your help, I appreciate!

Comment: You have to be very careful about letting your users customise page layout (using the raw HTML) as you may end up with a support headache when you want to redesign the base site at a later point.

Comment: Hi thought about that and that's why I choosed one template engine (Jinja2, I updated my post). What do you recommend to do then ? I need to allow them to change the whole design to fit their need, and also add new pages (flat ones). I'm a bit stuck :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I'll answer myself based on what I did and my research.

As Steve mentionned, you have to be very careful about letting users customise page layout.

**The risk must be well evaluated!**

In my case, letting users change the complete HTML/CSS/JS is possible, in a way, like [Posterous](http://www.posterous.com/) or [Tumblr](http://www.tumblr.com/) does.

The risks are :

- A user could add a javascript code that would collect auth cookie of other users. Doing so, this user could have access to any token auth for the admin part of each other users. *A simple solution is to avoid cross cookies between the admin part and the user website.*
- A user could try to execute code in the template, like Python, PHP,  Java, Ruby, etc (regarding what it is used). *The solution here is to use a template engine that disallow entirely the use of code, only tags*. [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/) for python is a perfect fit for that.

If those two conditions are well evaluated, the option "**Allow user to edit templates (stored in the database)**" is a good solution.

But if you are worried about too many hits the database could have, the last solution, aka "**Allow user to edit templates (stored in files)**", could be possible, if :

- You make sure the user can't access other folder that the template directory he can have access. *You can do it so with something like setting up a FTP server that use the database for user access (like ProFTPd with MySQL), and chrooting the user in his template dir. A quota is also very important to set up, in order to avoid your user to use his template dir as stockage device ;)*

Well, I think I covered the whole problem. It's possible I miss some points, if it's the case, please add a comment or a new post and I will complete the answer.